# Tag missing from wildcard search

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, search

I did a search for all tags starting with "google":

```
[google*]
```

And it returned this url:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google+or+google-spreadsheets+or+google-drive+or+google-apps+or+google-plus+or+google-calendar+or+google-search+or+google-maps+or+google-reader+or+google-chrome+or+google-contacts+or+google-groups+or+google-apps-script+or+google-analytics+or+google-account+or+google-documents+or+google-apps-email+or+google-talk+or+google-voice+or+google-forms

This doesn't include the [google-presentations](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-presentations) tag which currently has 12 questions.

Is there a limit to the number of tags that a wildcard tag search will match?

Comment: The number of tags matched is limited:

[Answer from Jeff on "Links from wildcard tag search results returning 404"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47993/59303)

[Because URLs of the form `http://example.com/tagged/foo+bar+baz` have a "path length limit" of about ~260 characters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48192/59303)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A while back there was some issue with the wildcard expansion generating excessively long URLs that would be rejected by the web server. [Jeff imposed an expansion limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37484/links-from-wildcard-tag-search-results-returning-404/47993#47993) as a workaround, which seems to limit the wildcard matches to the top 20 most popular applicable tags.