# Why can't I use [google] tag for Google Maps-related questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

[Rubén](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%C3%A9n) edited [my question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/80491/21486) 18 hours ago and removed [google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) tag from it.

When I visited [revisions page for that question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/80491/revisions), where [google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) tag still exists and hovered it, I can read:

> **Questions about** Google on a broad level and concerns **one or more of the following** web apps: Google Search, **Google Maps**, Gmail and Google Voice

(emphasis mine)

What am I missing? Why this tag was removed? Why this edit was accepted?

Answer (score 6):

Because it's a generic tag and is simply too broad. There is no app called "Google". One could argue for the search engine, but that's why we have [google-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-search).

You'll also note that the [tag wiki](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/google/info) provides further guidance:

> Use this tag if you're talking about Google services in general.

You're not talking about Google in general, but Google Maps specifically.

Related discussions:

- [Please don't double tag Google items](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/540/)
- [Why are more general tags getting removed from questions?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2495)

In my opinion, [google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) is a mostly useless tag.

Comment: Funny thing. Tag excerpt **was containing** information, that it can be used on questions about Google Maps. I pointed out, that in the light of this definition, my question was incorrectly purged out of this tag. Then you come, say, that tag is too generic and silently change tag excerpt. Not even a word, in your answer, that it was misleading and you fixed that.

Comment: Yes, the guidance was wrong. It was out of date and came from a time when we had few tags for Google Apps.